# SPAN does not inherit property

Tags: html, css, inheritance

Please advise what is a problem.

```
<style>
 .sp{display:table-cell;}
</style>
```

then

```
<span class="sp">
 test
 <span>
  test1
 </span>
</span>
```

I look into the both spans using chrome inspector, and see that outer is a cell, but inner does not inherit this property... What am I missing?

Comment: You are not specified class in inner span in html code.

Comment: You've defined a class, so only elements with a class of `sp` will be set to `display: table-cell;`. If you did `span { display:table-cell }` then both spans would have that CSS property.

Comment: change it to  `.sp, .sp span {display:table-cell;}`

Answer (score 0):

Please change from this

```
<style>
 .sp{display:table-cell;}
</style>
```

in to

```
<style>
 span{display:table-cell;}
</style>
```

Comment: Then all spans will get it. I needed only THIS span tree to get inheritance

Comment: then u can use this .sp,.sp span{display:table-cell;}, im notify only whats problem on you code :)

Answer (score 0):

The `display` property is not automatically inherited by child elements of the `span`.  Your expectation that this style will be inherited by nested tags is incorrect and inconsistent with the specification.

See: [the MDN documentation for the display property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display).

The following CSS style will achieve your goal:

```
.sp, .sp>span{display:table-cell;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`display` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#propdef-display) is not inherited, by its definition. It would actually be rather problematic if it were.

Thus, the rule affects only such elements that are in class `sp`.

To make it affect the inner `span` as well, you can set `class=sp` on it, too. Alternatively, you can use e.g.

```
.sp, .sp > span {display: table-cell; }
```

which affects any `span` child (but not inner descendants) of an element in class `sp`, too.

P.S. I have no idea of what what such settings might be useful for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly why, but some attributes can't be inherited like that.
But try this one to see what I'm talking about:

```
.sp, .sp span {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

Take a look:
**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/macmessa/NJtVJ/)**